SOLR Not Working 503 Error Netty dependencies have versions that do not match the versions specified in the azure-core-http-netty pom.xml file
We have an Azure Web App SOLR connected with Sitecore for Indexing. it was working great till Yesterday. Now the Azure Service is Not coming up with Error.

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
In the log file (httpplatform-stdout_***.txt) we can see the warning that states if SOLR is not running please look at this warnings carefully.

 2024-05-20 10:59:17.460Z WARN  c.a.c.h.netty.implementation.Utility - The following Netty dependencies have versions that do not match the versions specified in the azure-core-http-netty pom.xml file. This may result in unexpected behavior. If your application runs without issue this message can be ignored, otherwise please update the Netty dependencies to match the versions specified in the pom.xml file. Versions found in runtime: 'io.netty:netty-common' version not found (expected: 4.1.101.Final),'io.netty:netty-handler' version not found (expected: 4.1.101.Final),'io.netty:netty-handler-proxy' version not found (expected: 4.1.101.Final),'io.netty:netty-buffer' version not found (expected: 4.1.101.Final),'io.netty:netty-codec' version not found (expected: 4.1.101.Final),'io.netty:netty-codec-http' version not found (expected: 4.1.101.Final),'io.netty:netty-codec-http2' version not found (expected: 4.1.101.Final)

I did try to add the URL mentioned in the Link But was still at the same error.

Check the pom.xml file that sits in the root of your App Service.
Within that file, you should see a list of dependencies at the bottom like below:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc-id</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    ....

Navigate to dist/solrj-lib and look for io.netty:netty-common and confirm that the versions that are specified in the xml file match the ones you find in the folder.
If they dont match, then you need to either source the correct versions of the  dependencies or update the version numbers in the xml file. Be wary of updating the versions though, as it would seem you are not running the intended combination of files (the versions would have matched when initially installed - no idea what might have changed this in your situation).

Can you please help me navigate to "dist/solrj-lib" in Azure web app, like where in KUDU CMD will i get this path?

Sorry I am used to local SOLR install rather than cloud. But I assumed it would have the same set of files. In local instal, the dist folder sits in the root of the install.
